# Solr delete not working for some reason

Tags: java, search, solr

Just trying to delete all the documents, and did this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3E*:*%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E
```

then committed:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=%3Ccommit/%3E
```

I get the response:

```
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">17</int>
</lst>
</response>
```

But when I search I still get results back.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: where is the solr log, I couldn't find it!  I'm running on jetty.

Comment: Never mind, if you have a response, there's no error. What's your client platform? If it's Java you could just use SolrJ, or is there any particular reason you're not using it?

Comment: what docs do you get if you query `*:*` ?

Comment: If anyone is wondering, here is the SOLR docs on how to do these kind of deletions from a URL: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages

Comment: For me this did not help, but be sure check the linked issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057734/solr-cannot-delete-anything

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Not sure if it matters but you might encode the : too

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3E*%3A*%3C%2Fquery%3E%3C%2Fdelete%3E
```

Another thing to try is to use the POST method (the preferred way to call update):

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'
```

Comment: I then ran a separate 'code'(http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=<commit />) command after running this.  Many thanks

Answer (score 9):

I got stung with this one recently as well. Just remember that if you have updateLog is configured in solrconfig.xml, but there is no *version* field in the schema.xml

see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3432

I Spent a good hour on this one!!!

Comment: Fantastic comment. This was exactly my issue.

Answer (score 6):

Put the commit=true parameter in you GET request:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3E*:*%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E&commit=true`

Answer (score 2):

Remember to clear the browser cache! I thought I was having the same problem, but it turned out that the browser had just cached the result and was returning the cached page. D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

In Lucene wiki :

> it will still be found, because index
>   changes are not visible until, and a
>   new searcher is opened. To cause this
>   to happen, send a commit command to
>   Solr (post.jar does this for you by
>   default)

Maybe you can POST a `<commit/>` message to Solr.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true
```

Answer (score -2):

Probably you are missing a forward slash (`/`) after update and before question mark.

Current query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true
```

Revised query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update/?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true
```