# solr cannot delete anything

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm trying to delete documents on my solr server, but it doesn't work and I get no error.

I tried deleting via browser, curl and solrj and nothing works.

(browser and curl as explained here: [Solr delete not working for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358476/solr-delete-not-working-for-some-reason))
My solrj code is:

```
server.deleteByQuery("*:*");
server.deleteById("*");
server.deleteById("guid:*");
server.commit(true, true);

UpdateRequest update = new UpdateRequest();
update.deleteByQuery("*:*");
update.setCommitWithin(0);
server.request(update);
server.commit(true, true);

SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("*:*");//Search for everything/anything
query.setRows(10);
query.setRequestHandler("/query");
QueryResponse qr = server.query(query); 
SolrDocumentList result = qr.getResults();
for (SolrDocument doc : result) {
    Object id = doc.get("link");
    String names = (String) doc.get("description");
System.out.println(id + " " + names);
}
```

I always get results after executing this, or via the web interface, nothing changes (adding documents works by the way).

Anyone has and idea what I can try or what could be the reason for this?

**UPDATE:**

So I tried to setup everything from scratch again and I localized the error source: solr doesn't delete documents with my Schema.xml file, I still don't know why though:
[schema.xml on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8VdGZraa)

Comment: Version 4.0.0 alpha, with multicore setup running on jetty 8

Comment: Just tried 4.0.0 beta, same problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the reason:
[bug in solr 4.0.0 alpha](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3432)

the field:

```
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

is required for deleting in your schema.xml file if you enable the update log in your solrconfig.xml, if you don't have this field your delete update queries are ignored.

```
<updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">
  <updateLog>
    <str name="dir">${solr.data.dir:}</str>
  </updateLog>
</updateHandler>
```

This happens to everyone who uses the configurations from the examples in solr and just changes the Schema.xml file.

Comment: This answer solved the problem on my side. However, the line is present in both 4.0.0-ALPHA and 4.0.0-BETA:
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_4_0_0_ALPHA/solr/example/solr/conf/schema.xml?view=markup
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_4_0_0_BETA/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml?view=markup

So I think people just delete the line thinking it is not necessary...

Answer (score 3):

I have a working code like this:

```
SolrServer solrServer;
String url = "http://localhost:8080/solr";
solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(url);
solrServer.deleteByQuery("*:*");
solrServer.commit();
```

My Solr version is 3.6.1.

Comment: The thing is that the code works on the default setup from the example folder, but if i add my own schema.xml file i can't delete anything anymore and i don't know why or what is wrong with my schema.xml.

Comment: Surely, something is wrong with your schema.xml and solrconfig.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
//Delete particular column using Solr

SolrServer solrServer;

solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(url);

solrServer.deleteByQuery("columnName:value");

solrServer.commit();
```